# transparent PNG turns black

Tags: png

I created a logo with Photoshop. RGM Modus, saved as PNG-24 with transparent background. On my laptop it looks fine but on my friend's computer the image shows a black background.

Any idea what went wrong?

Comment: What application (and what version of the app) did you use on your friend's computer to view the PNG?

Comment: That program probably simply has a black background. Change the settings on the background and you see another color as background.

Answer (score 4):

What should a viewing program do with transparent? Make the laptop screen invisible and show what's behind it?

The viewer puts *something* behind the image. His program uses black. Yours shows a "fine" background, whatever that means.

Look at it in a html file that specifies the image *and* what to display it over. That's the only way to get a known result.

That's handy too since you can show how it looks against *different* backgrounds.

Answer (score -1):

Program that installed in your frends don't support transparent, use another program for view or check setting for transparent in your viewer